# Add all result to baseline

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-bicep, azure-defender

I have secure score finding VA1258 - Database owners are as expected.

In this case, the owners are how we need them so I need to add the results to the baseline.

How can I automate updating the baseline?

I've looked at the powershell command Set-AzSqlDatabaseVulnerabilityAssessmentRuleBaseline, but it doesn't support the express configuration.  I get the error:

> Vulnerability Assessment settings don't exist or invalid storage
> specified in settings 'storageContainerPath'

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [this forum thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1153031/azure-sql-vulnerability-assessment-express-configu), a Microsoft employee says that "the current PS cmdlets are not applicable to servers with express configuration". Try to use instead Vulnerability Assessment APIs to manage the Express Configuration. Here you will find a [sample script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/powershell-sample-vulnerability-assessment-azure-sql).